# Unable to update database using table adapter with datarows

Tags: c#, datarow, tableadapter

I am trying to update a table in my database using a tableadapter that takes  DataRows. These are rows created from a session datatable with `DataTable.Select()`.

`SaveDetailAdapter.Update(dr)` doesn't cause an error, but it doesn't update the table in the database. All the elements of the row are in the order that the adapter's stored procedure expect to see them.

If, however, I call
`Update(dr.ItemArray.GetValue(0), dr.ItemArray.GetValue(1), dr.ItemArray.GetValue(2))`

it works. So I can loop through and call the update and pass parameters, but not datarows.

Comment: What is the RowState property on the DataRow?

Comment: The row state is Unchanged.

Comment: I set the RowState using dr.SetModified(). However, I now get an SQL error that required params are not passed, but when I debug, I see that the ArrayItems have all the right values.

Comment: What is in the Parameters collection of the TableAdapter?  Are you setting those values in code anywhere?

Comment: This is my first time trying to pass a datarow to a tableadapter, so there is much I don't yet understand. My assumption was that the datarow/s would get passed wholesale to the SP. But on inspection of the datarow, it's just an array with no datatyping. Is there a way to get the datarow to keep the datatypes of the datatable that it came from?